# How to check if a text contains an element of an ArrayList

Tags: arraylist

I have a text and an array list. I would like to check if my text contains any element in the ArrayList, and if he does find it, to replace the space between two words with `"%"`.
Here's my code :

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String text, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    for (String i: list)
    {
        if (text.contains(list[i]))
        {
            text.replaceAll(" ", "%");

            System.out.println("done");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It gives me this error: `string cannot be converted to int` for the line `if (text.contains(list[i]))`. Any idea how else can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is a String. In that case `list[i]` does not make sense, since `i` inside of `list[i]` should be an index, which is an integer (e.g. `list[0]`, `list[1]`, but can not be `list["hello"]`).

So if you want to check that your text contains a String from list, you can use

```
if(text.contains(i))
```

---

Also, be aware that your result of

```
text.replaceAll(" ", "%");
```

is being ignored. If you want to keep the altered text, you can do that by storing the result of the replace into a new, separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<String> list` is not an array, it is a list. So you can get the elements of list by calling `get()` method.

e.g.

```
list.get(0) // returns the first element of the list
```

Also

```
for (String i: list) {
    // ...
}
```

is a foreach loop, a different version of

```
for(int x=0; x<list.size(); x++) {
    // ...
}
```

`i` corresponds to `list.get(x)`

You should change `text.contains(list[i])` to `text.contains(i)` because `i` stands for `list.get(x)`

> Q: How to check if a text contains an element of an ArrayList

After fixing the error you'll see that the variable `text` has not changed. Because in Java strings are immutable and `replaceAll()` method returns a new string. So you should assign the new value to the `text` variable:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\s", "%");
```

Here is the corrected version of the `stringContainsItemFromList()` method:

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String text, List<String> list)
{
     for (String i: list) {
        if(text.contains(i)) {
            text = text.replaceAll("\\s", "%");
            System.out.println("done");
            System.out.println(text);

             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `i` is a string and you're using it as a int

```java
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String text, ArrayList<String> list)
{
 for (String i: list) // HERE: i is an element of the list, not the index!

{
    if(text.contains(list[i])) // HERE: list[string] -> error!
    {
    text.replaceAll(" ", "%");

    System.out.println("done");
return true;
    }
}
    return false;
}
```

replace `text.contains(list[i])` for `text.contains(i)` and try to use more descriptive var names :)

Answer (score 0):

Something makes me believe, you actually need this !

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String text, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    for (String i: list) {
        if(text.contains(i)) {
            text = text.replaceAll(i, "%");
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println("done");
    return flag;
}
```